# Find for each positive integer $n$ the sum of the series $1 + 4 + 16 + 64 + ... + 4^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Would someone be able to help me find, for general positive integers, $n$ the sum of series $1 + 4 + 16 + 64 + ... + 4^n$ ?

I was using $(r^n - 1)/(r-1)$ to get it, but this doesn't give me the right values when I plug $n$ in. I couldn't find anything else online.

Comment: That's not an infinite series.

Comment: For $n=1$ note that 1+4 = 5 =(16-1)/3; for $n=2$ note that 1+4+16 = 21 = (64-1)/3,.... You should be using $(r^{n+1}-1)/(r-1)$; here $r=4$ and $r-1=3$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 1):

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^n 4^k = \frac{1-4^{n+1}}{-3}$$